# Matrix multiplication benchmarking on Titan RTX with double and single precisions

Tags: python, cuda, benchmarking, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to understand the difference in performances between single and double precisions of our GPU workstation.

Our workstation is equipped with two TITAN RTX GPUs, but I am running the benchmark on a sigle Titan RTX.
I am testing the performance with cublas matrix-matrix multiplications. I multiply 8192x8192 matrices that consist of random floats or doubles. To ensure that there is no mistake on my end, I also repeat this procedure in Python using cupy library, and the results are very similar.

The test results are ~75 ms per 1 multiplication for floats and ~2,000 ms for doubles.

If I had an older GPU, this would make a lot of sense, as 75*32 = 2,400~2000, so that my double-precision performance would be ~32 times poorer as expected from the table https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions.

However, my GPU has Compute Capability 7.5, therefore I expect degradation of the performance with doubles only by a factor of 2.

Other info: Ubuntu 18 LTS, nvcc 10.2, driver 440.82.

Here is the CUDA code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long mix(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c)
{
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 13);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 8);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 13);
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 12);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 16);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 5);
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 3);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 10);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 15);
    return c;
}


using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int deviceCount;
        cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
        cublasStatus_t err;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, 0);
        printf("Detected %d devices \n", deviceCount);
        printf("Device %d has compute capability %d.%d:\n\t maxshmem %d. \n\t maxthreads per block %d. \n\t max threads dim %d. %d. %d.\n ", 0,
                deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor, deviceProp.sharedMemPerBlock, deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock, deviceProp.maxThreadsDim[0],
                deviceProp.maxThreadsDim[1], deviceProp.maxThreadsDim[2]);

        cudaEvent_t start_d, stop_d;
        cudaEventCreate(&start_d);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop_d);

        //RND insicialization
        unsigned long seed = mix(clock(), time(NULL), 0);
       srand(seed);


        int N=8192;
        int Nloops=2;

        int memsize=N*N*sizeof(double);
        double *a = (double *)malloc(memsize);
        double *b = (double *)malloc(memsize);
        double *c = (double *)malloc(memsize);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                        a[i*N+j]=((double)rand() / RAND_MAX);
                        b[i*N+j]=((double)rand() / RAND_MAX);
                }

        double *a_d, *b_d, *c_d;

        cudaMalloc((void **)&a_d, memsize);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&b_d, memsize);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&c_d, memsize);
        cudaMemcpy(a_d, a, memsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(b_d, b, memsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        cublasHandle_t handle;
        cublasCreate(&handle);

        double alpha=1.0;
        double beta=0.0;


        auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        clock_t start1;
        start1 = clock();
        cudaEventRecord(start_d);

        if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess)
                printf("%s \n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
        for (int i=0; i<Nloops; i++)
                cublasDgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, N,N,N,&alpha,a_d,N,b_d,N,&beta,c_d,N);
        cudaEventRecord(stop_d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        start1 = clock() - start1;
       cudaEventSynchronize(stop_d);
        cublasDestroy(handle);
        float milliseconds = 0;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start_d, stop_d);
        std::cout << "Cuda event " << milliseconds /Nloops << " ms" <<endl;
        std::cout << " time elapsed " << start1 / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC /Nloops << '\n';
        cout << "time elapsed for 1 multiplication: " << ((double)chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count() )/(Nloops*1000.0)<< " milliseconds" <<endl;
        free(a); free(b); free(c);
        cudaFree(a_d); cudaFree(b_d); cudaFree(c_d);

}
```

And this is the python code that yields consistent results:

```
import cupy as cp
import time

iterations = 2
a = cp.random.rand(8192,8192).astype(cp.float64)
b = cp.random.rand(8192,8192).astype(cp.float64)

def ab(a,b,iterations):
  for i in range(iterations):
    cp.matmul(a,b,out=None)

ab(a,b,1) # warm up
cp.cuda.Device(0).synchronize()
t1 = time.time()
ab(a,b,iterations)
cp.cuda.Device(0).synchronize()
t2 = time.time()
total = (t2-t1)/iterations
print(total)
```

Comment: you are assuming that you are arithmetic limited, but you probably aren't in the double precision case

Comment: @talonmies I assume that I am limited arithmetically since if this was a bandwidth-limited problem, my performance would drop by a factor of 2 (as doubles are 64 bits, while floats are 32 bits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. In that table that I link in my quesiton, there is a footnote that says that for compute capability 7.5 (which is the case here) the performance is 2, but not 32, and for floats it is 64, which means that multiplication-addition operations for doubles are 32 times slower than for the floats.

If both the float and double problems were fully arithmetic-bound, I would expect the slowdown to be ~32. In reality, the slowdown is slightly smaller (2000/75 ~ 27), which may be a consequence of the problem with floats being bandwidth-bound, or maybe it is related to other things.